# Замена оператора сравнение

Tags: операторы, php

Добрый день. Подскажите, как можно заменить оператор сравнения? 
например

```
if ($otp == 1) {
$pravilo_otp = "==";
} else {
$pravilo_otp = "!=";
}

while($ser_row = $adb->fetch_array($sql)) {
if ($ser_row[$s_dver] $result $sort_dver )
```

Comment: а почему бы не заменить на функцию и условие будет выглядеть так

    if (pravilo_otp($s_dver,  $sort_dver))

Answer (score 2):

так ?

```
 $pravilo_otp = $otp==1?"==":"!="; //Тернарный оператор
```

ну а если надо ту if поменять, то весь ваш кусок кода меняем на вот это:

```
 if ($s_dver==$sort_dver)==($otp==1))
```

http://ideone.com/LnfDUR

Comment: подозреваю, что ключевой момент вопроса заключается в этом:

> ``if ($s_dver $pravilo_otp $sort_dver)``

Comment: неа, проблема именно в if ($s_dver $pravilo_otp $sort_dver)

Comment: @xEdelweiss сомнительно это вообще parse error

Comment: xEdelweiss, ага.

Comment: @eicto, я в курсе

Comment: @xEdelweiss @machanics вроде так, по крайней мере тесты прошло...

Comment: @eicto, интересный вариант. Здорово)

Comment: кто минуснул и почему ?

Answer (score 2):

*Не очень хотел бы встретить такое, но..*

```
$pravilo_opt = '==';
$s_dver = 5;
$sort_dver = 2;

$result = eval("return $s_dver $pravilo_opt $sort_dver;");
var_dump($result); // false
```

Само собой, за содержимым `$s_dver` и `$sort_dver` надо внимательно следить.

Как по мне, так уж лучше так:

```
if (..)
    $result = $s_dver == $sort_dver;
else
    $result = $s_dver != $sort_dver;

var_dump($result);
```

Если нет, то подумайте над логикой еще раз.

Comment: Эмм.. не много не то ( я подправил пример.. соррь не то привел

Comment: Так что не то? Подставьте новые переменные, поместите это всё в цикл и наслаждайтесь.  
И что у вас там за ``$result``?

Попробуйте удалить этот код, потратить остаток дня над придумыванием новых вариантов решения, а завтра на свежую голову написать что-то хорошее. *Не издеваюсь.*

Comment: Так и поступил! )